# A USB C device with Pass-through Data between devices and External Charger

Tags: usb, usb-c

Is there a device that allows two or more connected USB devices to communicate, yet their power be supplied by an external source (such as a USB power bank or charger).

I tried to make this illustration to clarify what I mean.

[image]

Comment: "Hub" might be the wrong word to use, since that is the name for a box that is connecting *multiple* USB devices to a host. It seems like you just need a USB-C "Y Power Splitter" cable/adapter. There are lots of those, but they may only supply power to one USB-C end. For example, to charge a phone while connecting a USB-C flash drive.

Comment: @Romen Thanks. The ones I found only have audio, USB 3.1 or USB C audio out, but do not allow communication between the devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB-C hubs with power pass-through are fairly common. Often sold with the [Power Delivery (PD)](https://www.usb.org/usb-charger-pd) mark followed by the power rating for that device. [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GDHD3VC) is one such hub that I use regularly to connect peripherals and charge simultaneously. However, this hub does not have a USB-C slave connection.

Hubs that also have a port for a USB-C slave device are more rare. Since you want to have an attached device that is also USB-C, I would recommend [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XF5489G). You plug your main device (phone/laptop) into male connection, your USB-C device that is the slave (flash memory, etc) into the bottom port, and the charger plugs into the port on the side.

Example:

```
   Laptop ---[_Hub_]---- Phone
               |
            Charger
```

Comment: Thanks. However, these hub connect to one USB C device and the other UCB C connection is for power input and does not allow communication between the USB C device and another USB C device.

Comment: That is incorrect. The second link I sent you has three USB-C connections. I worded my answer carefully so you can see that this is the one you want. The male connector goes to the master, one female port is for data and one female port is for power.

Comment: Answer edited to clarify further. Built in PD and OTG are some of the best features of USB-C and I hope devices like this become more common. Let me know if this answered your question.

Comment: Awesome! This should work! I didn't think of it this way! Thank you!